# Glibc Corrupted Double-Linked List

Tags: c, struct, glibc, realloc

I have a program that reads through a text file and separates it into chapter and paragraph structs.

```
struct paragraph
{
   char** lines;
   int numLines;
};

struct chapter
{
   struct paragraph** paragraphs;
   int numParagraphs;
};

struct book
{
   struct chapter** chapters;
   int numChapters;
};
```

Here is the offending code snippet, specifically the realloc() statements:

```
//int numChapters = -1;
//char**** book = (void*)0;
struct book* books = malloc(sizeof(struct book*));
books->chapters = malloc(sizeof(struct chapter));

books->numChapters = -1;

//char*** nextChapter;
struct chapter* nextChapter = malloc(sizeof(struct chapter));


while ( (nextChapter = readChapter(bookFile))->paragraphs[0] )
{
    if (++(books->numChapters) > 0)
    {
        books = realloc(books, sizeof(struct chapter*)*books->numChapters);
        books->chapters[books->numChapters - 1] = nextChapter;

    }
}
books = realloc(books, sizeof(struct chapter*)*books->numChapters);
books->chapters[books->numChapters] = (void*)0;

return books;
```

The functions called within this code snippet should work correctly, at least I'm banking on that fact. It's got to a be memory mismanagement issue. Thanks for any advice!

I should mention that it reads through the first few chapters and then it gets the error.

Comment: Actually, I'm failing to see where any "[double-]linked list" is ..

Comment: That error comes when doing the realloc in the if statement. It seems like it's running out of memory or something of that sort after it reads the first few chapters. Interesting note, however, removing that realloc statement completely allows my program to read the entire book.txt file, but it doesn't store everything properly...at all.

Comment: The memory management structures are corrupted before the realloc(). Run the program under valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need twice pointers in each structure? You have arrays for chapters, for paragraphs - no need to use twice pointers.

Provided code is more likely to use arrays, not lists. So if you are trying to use lists - I mentioned them in the end of answer. Otherwise, it is simpler to fix it to use arrays and here is the first problem:

```
if (++(books->numChapters) > 0)
{
    /* here books are reallocated */
    books = realloc(books, sizeof(struct chapter*)*books->numChapters);
    /* but here chapters which had not been reallocated are acessed */
    books->chapters[books->numChapters - 1] = nextChapter;

}
```

If you have a new chapter then why do you need to realloc books? Just realloc books->chapters:

```
if (++(books->numChapters) > 0)
{
    books->chapters = realloc(books->chapters, sizeof(struct chapter*)*books->numChapters);
    books->chapters[books->numChapters - 1] = nextChapter;

}
```

And in the end the same issue:

```
/* books are reallocated, size is bad - reallocated to size of numChapters * (pointer size) */
books = realloc(books, sizeof(struct chapter*)*books->numChapters);
/* perhaps access to non-allocated memory here */
books->chapters[books->numChapters] = (void*)0;
```

Should be:

```
books->chapters = realloc(books->chapters, sizeof(struct chapter)*books->numChapters);
// books->chapters[books->numChapters] = (void*)0;
```

Assigning NULL to the last element is not needed, because chapters has size of numChapters and accessing element numChapters cause access to non-allocaed memory, crash.

All the code above uses a conception of arrays, not linked lists.

To switch it to linked list it is necessary to use structures like the following:

```
struct paragraph
{
   struct paragraph *next; // <<-- this field is used to build
                           //      linked list of paragraphs
   char* lines;
   int numLines;
};

struct chapter
{
   struct chapter *next; // <<-- this field is used to build 
                         //      linked list of chapters
   struct paragraph* paragraphs;
   int numParagraphs;
};

struct book
{
   struct chapter* chapters;
   int numChapters;
};
```

Sure, appropriate allocations and assignment of "next" pointers are required.